# How do I use git tags to version an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying my hand at versioning the azure devops pipeline. I tried consulting ChatGPT which has indicated that using the following format should allow me to accomplish the task of using version tags in the pipeline itself:

```
- template: myPath/mytemplate.yml@templaterepo#v1.0.0
```

I went into the external repo `templaterepo` and added the git tag `v1.0.0` on the latest master commit in that same format as I have it tagged in the pipeline using it. When I try to validate the pipeline, it complains that it cannot find the repository: `templaterepo#v1.0.0`.

- Without the #Version appended to the end, it has no problem grabbing my template.
- I've tried editing the resources block that grabs the templates repo, however it doesn't fetch git tags like I've seen in other examples. Below is how I tried to edit it to grab tags instead of branches.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templaterepo
    type: git
    name: devops\templaterepo
    ref: refs/tags/*
    fetchDepth: 0
```

- My templates repo is in another project. I've ensured that the project service account has read access to the repository itself, and that there is a valid service connection.

This leaves me with several questions:

1. Is this specific method supported in Azure DevOps? I know it doesn't support all YAML features.
2. Am I doing this right?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Any insight would be greatly helpful

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Use that as your first reference, not ChatGPT. `templaterepo#v1.0.0` is not the right syntax. You define the tag on the `repository` resource, not on the reference to the template.

Comment: @DanielMann How do I define it on the repository resource? From what I saw it only allows me to do it if I have a pipeline artifact (something i don't really understand fully). I only ended up at ChatGPT because I'm the kind of person who in school would sit there and look at the 40 examples teach would throw on the board before understanding a concept. I enjoy the fact that I can ask iterations of questions and i see how it would work with mostly correct syntax before I go try the same thing and spend  2 hours not knowing why its not working, as I'm still learning how to do YAML.

Comment: You already have it defined, just incorrectly: `ref: refs/tags/*`. You specify the tag there, i.e. `refs/tags/1.0.0`. Again, *look at the documentation*.

Answer (score 0):

`ref: refs/tags/tagname` works to specify a tag. It needs to be specified directly and not through a variable or wildcard. Variables will just get treated as literal strings.

When referencing a variable in the resources block, the variable won't be evaluated at runtime. The resources block is resolved during the pre-processing phase, which occurs before variable substitution.